# Searching a functions source code

Tags: r, function

In R, you can view the source of a function as a function is simply another object.

I am looking for a way to search through this source code, without knowing the file that the source is saved in.

For example, I might want to know if the function `shapiro.test` contains the function `sort` (it does).

If `shapiro.test` was a string or a vector of strings I would use

```
grep('sort', shapiro.test)
```

But as `shapiro.test` is a function, this gives the error "Error in as.character(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'".

I've had no luck trying to coerce the function to a string. Just as an extra, I'm not expecting to be able to search through base functions as they are compiled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here a solution using `deparse`:

```
> grep ("sort", deparse(shapiro.test))
[1] 5
```

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap the function in `capture.output`, which will convert each line to an element in a character vector.

```
> grep("sort",capture.output(shapiro.test))
[1] 5
```

Or you could just call `edit(shapiro.test)` and use the text editor specified by `options(editor=)` to search through the function.

Comment: Both answers are similar and excellent. I gave the 'correct' to the other answer just seemed slightly neater. Thanks!